# uninitialized constant UploadsController::Bucket when trying to write general AWS::S3 Upload controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to write a general Amazon S3 uploader (will be used mostly for images) for my rails project. I was able to set up the environment in my console following http://amazon.rubyforge.org/.

I was able to follow the guide in the console. However, I had trouble when I applied it to my rails project. When I try to access my new view, I get the following error:

```
NameError in UploadsController#new 
uninitialized constant UploadsController::Bucket
```

Here is my controller:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
require 'aws/s3'

  def new
    photo_bucket = Bucket.find('photos')
    @photos = photo_bucket.objects
  end

  def create
    file = 'black-flowers.jpg'
    S3Object.store(file, open(file), 'photos')
  end
end
```

In my controller, my new action will contain the form for the upload and a list of all the photos.

My create action will just save the file. I haven't figured out how the params from the form will be passed into the controller yet, so ignore the 'black-flowers.jpg' line.

My guess is that I did not establish a connection in the controller.

**How do I establish a connection or fix this error?**

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bucket` is not a top level constant in this case. You probably want the `AWS::S3::Bucket` constant for new, and I'd assume something similar for `S3Object`.

Note that you may also want to look into the [Fog library](https://github.com/fog/fog) for this.

The fact that you haven't figured out how params will be passed in implies that you may also want to work through the Rails tutorials without S3 first.

Comment: IIRC params are passed as keys (I'll figure it out once I get there). :)
When I use `AWS::S3::Bucket` as suggested, I get this error: `undefined method `find' for AWS::S3::Bucket:Class`. Any clue?

Comment: yes, controllers have a params method that is a hash representing the request parameters. I honestly don't know why `find` is not being found on Bucket, since it is documented as being part of that class

Comment: Thanks anyway, Jim. I appreciate your help and suggestions. I'll ask this in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it was solved by just checking all files required were provided and restarting the server